# How do I flip the toggle button to jQuery function

Tags: jquery, mobile, arduino, html

The following functions do the same thing with a [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile) site, flip the toggle button, use it in.

```
<script>
    function updateControls() {
        $.getJSON('/status.json', function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                $('#'+key).val(value).slider('refresh');
            });
        });
    }

    $('select').bind('change', function(event) {
        element = event.target.id;
        if (element.substr(0, 6) == 'outlet') {
            eleid = element.substr(6, 2);
        }
        else {
            eleid = 0;
        }

        command = event.target.value;
        $.get('/cmd', { 'eleid' : eleid, 'cmd' : command });
    });
    $('#page1').bind('pageinit', updateControls);
</script>
```

Comment: so your question is.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap code inside `document.ready` also use `.on` instead of `.bind` as `.bind` is deprecated.

```
$('#page1').on('pageinit', updateControls);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted version of your code:

```
<script>
    function updateControls() {
        $.getJSON('/status.json', function (json) {
            $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                $('#' + key).val(value).slider('refresh');
            });
        });
    }

    $('select').on('change', function (event) {
        element = event.target.id;
        if (element.substr(0, 6) == 'outlet') {
            eleid = element.substr(6, 2);
        } else {
            eleid = 0;
        }

        command = event.target.value;
        $.get('/cmd', {
            'eleid': eleid,
            'cmd': command
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        updateControls();
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to do the same with the submit buttons as with the selects, the code would be:

```
<script>
    function updateControls() {
        $.getJSON('/status.json', function (json) {
            $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                $('#' + key).val(value).slider('refresh');
            });
        });
    }

    $('select').on('change', function (event) {
        element = event.target.id;
        if (element.substr(0, 6) == 'outlet') {
            eleid = element.substr(6, 2);
        } else {
            eleid = 0;
        }

        command = event.target.value;
        $.get('/cmd', {
            'eleid': eleid,
            'cmd': command
        });
    });


    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {
        element = event.target.id;
        if (element.substr(0, 6) == 'outlet') {
            eleid = element.substr(6, 2);
        } else {
            eleid = 0;
        }
        command = event.target.value;
        $.get('/cmd', {
            'eleid': eleid,
            'cmd': command
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            updateControls();
        });
</script>
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to event to happen on button click:

```
<script>
    function updateControls() {
        $.getJSON('/status.json', function (json) {
            $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                $('#' + key).val(value).slider('refresh');
            });
        });
    }

    $('select').on('change', function (event) {
        element = event.target.id;
        if (element.substr(0, 6) == 'outlet') {
            eleid = element.substr(6, 2);
        } else {
            eleid = 0;
        }

        command = event.target.value;
        $.get('/cmd', {
            'eleid': eleid,
            'cmd': command
        });
    });


    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {
        updateControls();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with the submit button and do the same??

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand you.

Comment: #PAGE1, #PAGE2, #PAGE3, #PAGE4, #PAGE5 in dont working.

    $(document).ready(function () {
        updateControls();
    });

Comment: @Selçuk What is `#PAGE1, #PAGE2, #PAGE3, #PAGE4, #PAGE5`?

Comment: example mobile webduino site;

http://www.efegüvenlik.com/AkilliEv-V.2/index.html

#page3 or #page4 in slider script state not read :(
I want to work on script state all pages...

webduino file;

http://www.efegüvenlik.com/AkilliEv-V.2/DimmerDeneme.ino